# Durée de la bêta — Duration of the beta

Tags: discussion, area51, beta-phase

En regardant les stats du site sur Area51, je me suis rendu compte que visiblement le site est en bêta depuis un bon moment, et la "barre de progression" correspondant à la bêta semble remplie à 100%.

Comme je suis relativement nouveau sur le StackExchange, je me demande à quoi est liée la durée d'une bêta pour un site donné, quels critères sont importants pour que le site rejoigne le StackExchange au final?

---

When looking at the stats of the site on Area 51, I noticed that clearly the site has been in beta for a good length of time, and that the "progress bar" corresponding to the beta seems to be progressed to 100%.

As I'm relatively new to StackExchange, I wonder what the duration of a given site's beta is linked to; what criteria are important for the site to be able to join StackExchange's launched sites?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Au départ l'idée était d'évaluer la viabilité du site après 90 jours (il en reste quelques traces dans les indicateurs sur Area 51). On s'est vite aperçu que 90 jours était bien trop court pour la plupart des sites, et qu'[un site pouvait passer très longtemps en béta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) (certains y sont restés plus d'un an). Mais il y a quand même une limite : [plusieurs sites ont été fermés récemment car leur activité était insuffisante](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/).

Ce site ne risque pas d'être fermé demain, mais il n'est pas non plus sorti de l'auberge. Notre trafic est en très légère augmentation, en partant de très bas. Vous pouvez aider en [promouvant le site](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-promotion). Si vous avez des idées de promotion, vous pouvez [poster sur Méta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion+site-promotion) pour avoir de l'aide (sous forme de conseils, de matériaux promotionnels, de main d'œuvre, voire même de financement).

---

Originally the idea was to make or break after 90 days (you can see traces of this on the Area 51 indicators). It was quickly realized that 90 days was too short for most sites, and that [sites could take a long time in beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) (some more than a year). But there is such a thing as too long: [some sites were recently closed for inactivity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/).

This site is not at risk of imminent closure, but it hasn't made it yet either. Our traffic is increasing very very slowly, and we're starting from low numbers by Stack Exchange standards. You can help by **[promoting the site](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-promotion)**. If you have any promotion idea, feel free to [post on Meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion+site-promotion) to get help (in the form of advice, material minions, maybe even financing).

Answer (score 5):

C'est expliqué dans [ce billet du blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/). Il date de 2010, mais il explique assez bien les bases.

Answer (score 2):

Sur la [fiche Area51 de French Language and Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage), on voit bien que le site manque de questions par jour. Tous les indicateurs sont au vert sauf celui là. Il faudrait donc que le nombre de questions par jour augmente pour que le site sorte de le béta.