# A quand la fin de la bêta ?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

Bonjour,

En me baladant sur l'Area 51, j'ai vu que la beta avait commencé il y a plus de six ans, sans jamais en sortir.

Les critères ont plutôt l'air en forme, bien que le nombre de questions par jour soit bas.

Pensez-vous qu'un jour le French Language sortira ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327/dur%C3%A9e-de-la-b%C3%AAta-duration-of-the-beta?rq=1

Comment: The "possible duplicate" was made in 2012, that's why i'm asking again here

Comment: However, [Zistoloen's answers](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/424/12177) in 2013 seems still valid today.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Durée de la bêta — Duration of the beta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327/dur%c3%a9e-de-la-b%c3%aata-duration-of-the-beta)